# In Kedro, How to specify layer to parameters.yml?

Tags: kedro

Currently, I'm using kedro and kedro-viz.

I can specify a layer of dataset from catalog.yml.

```
hoge:
  type: MemoryDataSet
  layer: raw
```

but I don't know how to do it with parameters.yml

```
step_size: 1
learning_rate: 0.01
```

if it can be done not in parameters.yml but in run.py, I want to see example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment layers can only be specified for datasets, not for nodes or parameters.

If you have a specific use case for adding layers to nodes/parameters, please let us know by opening a feature request in the Kedro repo: https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/issues